# Change color of a word in placeholder TextInput

Tags: react-native, placeholder, textinput

I have a TextInput. Is there any way to change the color of a word in TextInput's placeholder?
Ex: How(`color red`) are you? (`placeholder` attribute)

Comment: `TextInput` only allows [`placeholderTextColor`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#placeholdertextcolor) single text color for placeholder. You can create a custom placeholder component (`Text` or label component) that allows you to set different text color by range or substring and position that component on top of the text input.

Comment: [Nesting `Text` components](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#nested-text) will achieve the custom placeholder effect you are looking for.

Comment: @Amar After is set `placeholder=new Component`?

Comment: Please, can you give me an example?